# Start-Process : This command cannot be executed completely because the system cannot find all the information required

Tags: powershell

I can start `.bat`, and `.docx`, files in a ps1 script but not `.url`.  I would like to have the pid to stop the process (IE tab) later.

```
$app = Start-Process My_browser_link.url -passthru
```

Comment: So you want to stop a specific tab within IE?

Comment: This isn't straight forward:

https://powertoe.wordpress.com/2010/11/10/finding-the-thread-pid-that-belongs-to-a-tab-in-ie-8-with-powershell/

Comment: At minimum I want to start a tab in IE using a .url file.

Comment: You could  `$app = Start-Process 'C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe' -ArgumentList 'My_browser_link.url'` but this will give the parent process of IE rather than the specific thread, which if you `stop-process` will close all tabs as IE generates a separate thread per tab on the fly after opening the host process. This was how they were able to get around having separate x86 and x64 versions of IE.

Comment: @ BenH  This opens up a new instance of IE each time so this will work for me.  Not fond of the idea of have so many instances of IE open, but it does work, each instance has it own pid to it can be stopped using the returned pid.  The issue now it that the ArgumentList is being ignored.

Answer (score 0):

if my understanding of your question is correct, you can use:

```
start-process  -FilePath "C:\temp\Google.url"
```

It will use your default browser to open the url file.

Comment: This unfortunately does not answer the question. `Start-process .url` doesn't return the process information. And even if it did, most browsers open up a separate thread inside of the host process, so killing the returned process will close all tabs rather than just the one opened.